# Effect of decreasing mash temp?

Tags: mash, temperature

Let's say I mash in at 65 C and over an hour it drops to 60 C - will this have a detrimental effect on my brew?

Comment: What material is your mash tun made from?   My cooler only loses 1-3 F over a similar time span.

Answer (score 7):

The bulk of the starch-sugar conversion happens in the first 15 minutes of the mash, so that's probably not a big problem.   You might need to mash for 90-120 minutes rather than 60 to get a really good, full conversion, though.

I usually have to do a longer mash when I'm mashing "cool" (which you are), anyway.

Comment: Agreed on the time.  At that temp conversion takes longer.

Answer (score 3):

I have experimented with a couple overnight mashes.  I mash in and hit my 154F mash temp, close the cooler and wrap it in few heavy towels and an old sleeping bag.  I know that normally my cooler holds the 152-154F temp for at least 60minutes.  So I am not worrying about conversion time.  But in the morning my mash may be at 135F.

So to address flavor concerns there aren't any that I have noticed with a cooling mash.  Conversion in your case is still a concern as you mashed in cool and lost temp pretty quickly.  Outside of conversion, I wouldn't worry about flavor issues.